# Roots Theme: How to Remove Sidebar on Tribes Calendar?

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I am using the Tribes calendar [Tribest Events Calendar](http://tri.be/shop/wordpress-events-calendar/) and I want the sidebar from my site to be removed. I have gone through this post, but it doesnt work: http://discourse.roots.io/t/roots-and-modern-tribes-events-calendar/603

I have created the duplicate default-template.php but nothing happens.

I was having the same issue with woocommerce until I added "'is_woocommerce'," to the lib/config.php file and it removed it for woocommerce. Is there the same hack that I can use for the Tribes calendar. I just dont know what to script in: "'is_tribes' (???)," I hope someone can help smile

Thanks for any feedback that you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin provides [conditional template tags](https://gist.github.com/jo-snips/2415009) (a.k.a. functions) in the format `tribe_is_*()`.

E.g. conditionals for calendar pages: `tribe_is_upcoming()`, `tribe_is_month()`, and `tribe_is_day()` (I believe there are other views in the Pro version of The Events Calendar plugin.)

To remove the sidebar from calendar pages in the Roots-based theme, you would pass `"tribe_is_upcoming"`, `"tribe_is_month"`, and `"tribe_is_day"` to the instantiation of the [the `Roots_Sidebar` class in `lib/config.php`](http://roots.io/the-roots-sidebar/).  To also remove it from single event pages, pass `"tribe_is_event"`.